# No me oculta el div

Tags: jquery

Tengo este codigo en jquery

```
pais_co2 = "Colombia";
if (pais_co2 == "Colombia"){
        $("#mensajeCo").is(":visible");
        console.log("funciona show");  

}else{
        $("#mensajeCo").is(":hidden");
        console.log("funciona hide");
}
})
```

estoy intentando que si el se cumple la condicion se muestre un div, de lo contrario se oculte.
mi codigo html donde se encuentra el div es el siguiente

```
<div id="mensajeCo">
<h1> algo</h1>
</div>
```

Las condiciones se cumplen, pero no me esta funcionando el ocultar o mostrar. He intentado tambien esto

```
  pais_co2 = "Colombia";
    if (pais_co2 == "Colombia"){
      function mostrar(){
            $("#mensajeCo").show();
            console.log("funciona show");  
     }
    }else{
      function ocultar(){
            $("#mensajeCo").hide();
            console.log("funciona hide");
    }
    }
    })
```

Y sigue sin funcionar. Como podría solucionar esto? Agradezco cualquier aporte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que deberia funcionar es la ultima parte quitando la declaracion de function

```js
pais_co2 = "Colombia";
if (pais_co2 == "Colombia"){
    $("#mensajeCo").show();
    console.log("funciona show"); 
}else{
    $("#mensajeCo").hide();
    console.log("funciona hide");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mensajeCo">
<h1> algo</h1>
</div>
```